# Code in Try catch is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

My try catch doesnt work when I start it up.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        double c = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text);
        c = Multiply(c, c);
        Button1.Text = "c.ToString()";
    }
    catch { Button1.Text = NaN; }
}
```

miss used the "". I apologise for the mistake

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: what is `NaN`? Also, "c.ToString()" should be without quotes. One last thing, try using `double.TryParse` and you don't need to put try/catch here.

Comment: Unable to replicate the described behavior.  This `catch` structure catches exceptions for me.

Comment: @David I doubt strongly that the catch does not work. The code in the catch is faulty. I guess this does not compile

Comment: @MongZhu: I also doubt that the catch does not work.  Because it does.  But the question claims that it doesn't.  That's exactly what I'm pointing out.

Comment: you don't need to apologize. You stated a problem, and thus you need to show the real code. This you did. So everything is fine. You should in future be a little more clear in the problem description. Expecially post the error message if the compiler gives you one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
try
{
    double c = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text);
    c = Multiply(c, c);
    Button1.Text = c.ToString();
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    Button1.Text = "NaN";
}
```

**edit**: You put the c.ToString() between the " ", that doesn't work.

**edit 2:** I put the NaN between " ", I am not sure what you want to do with NaN.

Comment: aw thank you it worked. that i didn't see that myself

Comment: "You put the c.ToString() between the " ", that doesn't work." it should work perfectly, it will just not give you the content of `c` but simply the string `"c.ToString()"`

Comment: `"that doesn't work"` - Well, it "works" in that it successfully sets that literal string value to the button.  If that's what the OP was asking then the question wasn't clear *at all*.

Answer (score 2):

Would it not be better to handle the conversion from string to double more gracefully and not use a try catch:

```
double c = 0;
if (double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out c))
{
    c = Multiply(c, c);
    Button1.Text = c.ToString();
}
else
{
    Button1.Text = "NaN";
}
```

Comment: then i get this error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS8026 Feature 'out variable declaration' is not available in C# 5. Please use language version 7 or greater. Algorithm C:\Users\pieter\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\WebSites\Algorithm\FpCalc.aspx.cs 31 Active

Comment: I've updated the code snippet to support earlier language syntax - notice the explicit declaration of `c` before the `double.TryParse()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `c.ToString();` instead of `"c.ToString();"` in your code.

```
try
{
    double c = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text);
    c = Multiply(c, c);
    Button1.Text = c.ToString();
}
catch { Button1.Text = "NaN"; }
```